# How can I have dedicated set of users for each URL I am testing through Jmeter CSV data set config?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a jmeter script, in which I have added the CSV data set config element and I am passing 10 urls in the csv.
Aim- is to have 70 users doing all the transactions starting from login to logout in each of the url.
Example- first 70 users will test url1
Second 70 users will test url 2 and so on
So in total I should have 700 users testing for the 10 websites. Could you please help on how I can achieve this.

I have tried to change the sharing mode in csv data set config by keeping the number of threads as 70. I am able to see that the same 70 users are going into each url and completing the transactions.
I am expecting each url to have 70 users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) to read the line from the CSV file which is equal to the current loop number of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group).

Something like:

```
${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().get(vars.getIteration() - 1),)}
```

This way all 70 users will read 1st line during 1st iteration, 2nd line during 2nd iteration, etc.

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this method! Is there a way by which there could be 70 users in each url and can perform the transactions on the 10 urls simultaneously? For example simultaneous login of all the 700 users i.e 70 users in each tenant.

Comment: If you want to perform a certain transaction at the same time - take a look at [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer). If you want 700 concurrent users - just increase the number of threads in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) or add more Thread Groups if virtual users represent different groups of business users.